# Unable to read fixed width (6E12) numbers in matlab.

Tags: matlab, text, io

I'm having trouble reading some fixed width (6E12) data from a text file.
Notice that there are leading spaces in the file.

The first line isnt that important.
However, starting on the 2nd line I want to read 59 values.

### file.txt

```
 PleaseAnswer    3 ,   ThisQuestion    40
 0.00000E+00 4.78181E+01-4.76356E+01 3.76280E-01 0.00000E+00 1.59238E+00
 1.88171E+00 1.73928E-06 0.00000E+00 3.57826E+01 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 3.75261E-07 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 3.28103E+01 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00 0.00000E+00
 ...
```

### end file.txt

As you will see below, I encounter the problem with the 2nd and 3rd values due to the negative sign. I dont understand why there isnt a leading space. Almost all my numbers should have a leading space, except the negative ones.

### me trying to read this file

```
fid = fopen(filename);
dontcare = textscan(fid, '%s %d %s %s %n', 1);
fixme = textscan(fid, '%12s', 59, 'Delimiter', '', 'Whitespace', '');
fixme{1}

ans = 

    ' 0.00000E+00'
    '4.78181E+01-'
    '4.76356E+01 '
    '3.76280E-01 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '1.59238E+00'
    ' 1.88171E+00'
    '1.73928E-06 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '3.57826E+01 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '0.00000E+00'
    ' 0.00000E+00'
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '0.00000E+00 '
    '0.00000E+00'
    ' 0.00000E+00'
    ...
```

### end me trying to read file

Comment: I must be missing something. Why does it capture spaces at the beginning of lines, but not in between values? Also, notice the last value on lines isnt even 12 chars but 11! I thought I was making matlab give me 12.

Comment: I can get this to "work" by using '%12f' instead of '%12s' or '%12c'. However, I still dont know how to capture the spaces correctly when reading the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can tokenize using regular expressions. This solution uses a dyamic array, so if you read in a large file you'll want to get the line count a priori to pre allocated. Not the most elegant, but it works.

```
fid = fopen('file.txt','r');

line = fgetl(fid); % ignore first line
l=1;
done = false;
 while ~done
    line = fgetl(fid); 
    if line ~= -1 %empty line is returned
       [s,e] = regexp(line, '-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+E[+-][0-9]+','start','end'); %not sure why tokens aren't working
       for i=1:numel(s)
          data(l,i) = str2double(line(s(i):e(i))); %grab the ith match between start and end
       end
        l=l+1;
    else
        done = true;
    end
 end

 data
```

**Outputs:**

```
>> test

data =

         0   47.8181  -47.6356    0.3763         0    1.5924
    1.8817    0.0000         0   35.7826         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0    0.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0   32.8103         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0
```